# Keep buttons in view when keyboard opens (android)

Tags: android, keyboard, resize, window, view

I have an `EditText` inside of a `DropDown` with two buttons at the bottom (save/cancel). When the user clicks on the `EditText`, the keyboard opens and covers up the two buttons which makes it inconvenient. I would like these buttons to stay on top of the keyboard, but below the `EditText`. I tried declaring resizing in my manifest but it is no use since the action takes place in my `DropDown` and not in my activity. I understand there is a way to do this programically but need a little help, thank you. Heres the code:

```
 layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.layout.main));
            pw = new PopupWindow(layout,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, true);
            pw.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
            pw.setOutsideTouchable(true);
            pw.showAsDropDown(dropdown1);

          pw.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
                   //This does not work
```

Answer (score 0):

The setting is part of the manifest.  In the activity you can set android:windowSoftInputMode to adjustPan or adjustResize.  On resize the entire activity will be layed out again for the smaller size.  For pan, it will be scrolled up or down, with the promise that the textbox with the focus will be in the view. This is the only control you have over it.  The default is to let the system choose, which it does based on the presence of scrolling elements.  It sounds to me like pan will probably work for you.

Comment: Yes I understand that, however when I declare it in the manifest it has no effect on my dropdown window, it still uses the default and pans. The pan is not the option I want because it still covers the button, I need resize